# Why am I getting this weird anomaly with the loop cut?

Tags: modeling

At first, the loop cuts of the arm and the shoulder weren't joined, so I merged them and I got these uneven areas. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Comment: you must have a face inside your topology, press Z to see in Wireframe mode, select and delete the inner face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a face inside your topology, press Z to see in Wireframe mode, select and delete the inner face